# Creating table from select results fails with error 292 "wrong number of arguments: "

Tags: python, hana

Connecting to SAP HANA using the official, semi-unsupported `hdbcli` Python module.

I'm trying to create a table from a subquery, which has some placeholders:

```
>>> cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE temporary_table AS (SELECT ? AS a FROM DUMMY) WITH DATA', [1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/some-masked-path-here/hdbcli/dbapi.py", line 369, in execute
    ret = self.__execute(operation, tuple(parameters))
  File "/some-masked-path-here/hdbcli/dbapi.py", line 244, in __execute
    ret = self.__cursor.execute(operation, parameters=parameters, iscall=iscall)
Error: (292, 'wrong number of arguments: ')
```

(In my actual case I'm trying to create a temporary table, but this does not change the outcome)

If I change my query to a simple select from subquery instead of a `CREATE TABLE`, it works fine:

```
>>> cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM (SELECT ? AS a FROM DUMMY) AS sub', [1])
True
```

It also works if I change my inner `SELECT` to return a constant instead of using a placeholder:

```
>>> cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE temporary_table AS (SELECT 1 AS a FROM DUMMY) WITH DATA', [])
True
```

---

**UPDATE:** I have tested this with the officially supported ODBC driver via `pyodbc` as well, and a very similar problem manifests:

```
>>> cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE temporary_table AS (SELECT ? AS a FROM DUMMY) WITH DATA', [1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

While a simple subselect still works via ODBC as well:

```
>>> cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM (SELECT ? AS a FROM DUMMY) AS sub', [1])
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0xb70f0b80>
```

---

I am at a loss here; I've tried everything that I could think of, but still can't figure out why a `CREATE TABLE` query cannot use placeholders. Any help with figuring this mess out will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same with Hana Studio. It also fails. So this is not Python specific. IMHO you have a better chance for an answer if you ask this in the [SAP community network](http://scn.sap.com/welcome) since this is where the experts are around.

Comment: I've already asked there; seems to be a bug in HANA, as all I got was suggestions to work it around by issuing separate `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT...SELECT` statements.